# Is there a terminal provided for remote repository on Github or GItLab website?

Tags: github, gitlab, remote-control

Is there a terminal provided for remote repository on GitHub or GitLab website? Just like we can change a file and commit the changes in the website.

I am a React developer and not happy with cloning a heavy repository just for `npm run build`.

I don't expect this functionality exists but it's just a little hope.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out [repl.it](https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/06-github-and-run-button)

Answer (score 1):

**Gitlab** offers a full featured web IDE for inline repository files editing.

Please look at the following screenshot:

[image: Web IDE]

**Edit**

Here is a screenshot about the terminal activation button.

[image: Terminal activation button]

Comment: Wow, Thank you for the insight! Although, I don't see a terminal like a Bash for executing code and extra. There is no terminal in the IDE, right?

Comment: There is a terminal building on the top right of web IDE.

Comment: Hmm, I  am afraid I can't find that terminal.

Comment: @Shawn I added a screenshot shwoing the terminal activation button.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, GitHub offers:

- a web-based online IDE (still in beta) with [the `github.dev` web-based editor](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/the-githubdev-web-based-editor): just press dot <kbd>.</kbd>.
- an actual online IDE and build environment with [GitHub Codespace](https://github.com/features/codespaces) (but [not free](https://docs.github.com/en/billing/managing-billing-for-github-codespaces/about-billing-for-codespaces))
  [image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/codespaces/codespaces-diagram.png]

In both case, you don't need to clone the repository.

Comment: Oh, that's fantastic!. So If I use the second method "Github Codespace". I will be able to use the built-in terminal to execute code. right?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: OCt. 2021: new features: https://github.blog/changelog/2021-10-27-new-codespaces-features-launching-at-universe-2021/